# Number of active workers in Azure Functions Premium Plan?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

In my Premium App Svc Plan, I've deployed several function apps. Afaik, each has its own scale-out settings. Is there any way to see, on an app svc plan level, to see how many workers were active during what time (time-series) and what function app they belong to?

Thank you and cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure functions will run on all instances. If you want to know how many workers are running, you can check it on Azure portal.

Just click **Process explorer** under **Monitoring** part. You will find all the instances that running your function apps.

[image]

Note that this count doesn't include the pre-warmed workers, if you want to see the total count including the pre-warmed workers, you can use **Live Metrics** under **Investigate** part to check it. You functionapps currently are not running on Pre-warmed intances. As the app scales out, it first scales into the pre-warmed instances.

[image]

Comment: The OP asked for a historical / time series metric. While this answer is useful to point you to the live situation, I still don't see a way to look at historical data.

Comment: @Bogdan You could check this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-check-elastic-premium-plan-function-app-allocated/ba-p/2697852